# Reducing the dimensions of a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor with the following shape:

```
> tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1440)
```

How do I reduce such a shape so that I can get the following:

```
> tf.Tensor: shape=(1440,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`tf.squeeze`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze):

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.random.uniform((1, 1440))
print(tensor.shape
```

```
TensorShape([1, 1440])
```

And now:

```
squeezed = tf.squeeze(tensor)
print(squeezed.shape)
```

```
TensorShape([1440])
```

If you really want the comma format for the shape, turn it to NumPy:

```
tf.squeeze(s).numpy().shape
```

```
(1440,)
```